# invalid csp nonce issue

Tags: javascript, php, apache, nonce

I am trying to secure my JavaScript code with a `nonce` by using a line like this in `.htaccess apache`:

```
default-src 'self' 'nonce-%{base64:%{reqenv:UNIQUE_ID}}';
```

and then on the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="'.$_SERVER ['UNIQUE_ID'].'">' ... code ... '</script>
```

The trouble is I get `nonces should only use the base64 charset` in

https://cspscanner.com/

Probably expects text there, just checking.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: expects: "default-src  'self'  'nonce-bsP5ZZn6H3zVUssWssX4AZgS';"

Comment: Are you looking for `base64_encode($_SERVER ['UNIQUE_ID'])` ?

Comment: Well, if the landlord will not agree to cspnonce i will have to settle for that. thank you Daniel